# android studio resource identifier not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am just doing my thing with the java files and everything, when 4 errors pop up when i try to run the app:

```
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'versioncode' in package 'android'

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'versionname' in package 'android'

Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'minsdkversion' in package 'android'

Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetsdkversion' in package 'android'
```

So i try to edit these:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:minsdkversion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetsdkversion="17" >
```

But it just goes back right after i try to start up.
Any ideas?

It says: `files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited.`

So i found out i was in the wrong manifest, i have been editing some stuff, but still it does not work, same errors.

```
<manifest android:versioncode="1"
        android:versionname="1.0" package="com.learn2crack" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="9" android:targetsdkversion="17">
            <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Login">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
                            </category></action></intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Register">
                </activity>
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Registered">
                </activity>
                <activity android:label=" USER PANEL" android:name="Main">
                </activity>
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="PasswordReset">
                </activity>
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ChangePassword">
                </activity>
            </application>
            <!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
                </uses-permission></uses-permission></uses-sdk></manifest>
```

Now this have been fixed after i retyped some of the android:versions and targets, and removed the uses-sdk after they were already specified in the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited => You must not edit those files because they are generated.

You are not editing the right `AndroidManifest` !

You have to edit this one (For Android Studio) : app/src/main/AndroidManifest

Comment: But its not the same, and i tried alot now, cant seem to fix these resource identifier error

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

try this code